# Reducing API Calls in Salesforce

Tags: apex, rest-api

I have a requirement to mimic the standard List View functionality using custom lwc component. For that I am using Salesforce REST API to get List View information. But the problem with that is there would be many API calls that will get counted against the limit. Then I tried with Composite API so that I can reduce the number of API calls but looks like the limitation with this approach is that you can add upto 25 sub requests only , this approach may fail if we have more than 25 list views.

Is there any other approach by which we can mimic standard list view functionality with lesser API calls?

Comment: Not sure if i get your question correctly, I assume you are using `data-table` to mimic listview functionality. to get data for `data-table` you should call apex method where you retrieve data you need.

Comment: Yes we are using data-table only. But we can't get List View information directly from SOQL. We need to do API calls to get the List View details. With this approach there could be too many API calls

Comment: I assume the API calls are for getting the list UI metadata?

Comment: Yes correct. We are making REST API callout to fetch list view metadata like - SOQL or records etc